# What is `git diff --patience` for?

Tags: git, diff

How does the patience algorithm differ from the default `git diff` algorithm, and when would I want to use it?

Comment: Maybe it matches moved code and modified lines which can be much slower

Comment: I've extracted a standalone script for Patience Diff from Bazaar, you can find it in [another SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599456/textually-diffing-json/4599500#4599500).

Comment: A followup question. When should I not use patience diff?

Comment: There is also the `--histogram` parameter which "...extends the patience algorithm to "support low-occurrence common elements" http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff.html

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can read [a post from Bram Cohen](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128181055/http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bram-Cohen-speaks-up-about-patience-diff-td2277041.html), the author of the patience diff algorithm, but I found [this blog post](http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2010/05/patience-diff.html) to summarize the patience diff algorithm very well:

> Patience Diff, instead, focuses its energy on the low-frequency high-content lines which serve as markers or signatures of important content in the text. It is still an LCS-based diff at its core, but with an important difference, as it only considers the longest common subsequence of the signature lines:
>
> > Find all lines which occur exactly once on both sides, then do longest common subsequence on those lines, matching them up.

When should you *use* patience diff?  According to Bram, patience diff is good for this situation:

> The really bad cases are ones where two versions have diverged
> dramatically and the developer isn't being careful to keep patch sizes
> under control. Under those circumstances a diff algorithm can occasionally
> become 'misaligned' in that it matches long sections of curly brackets
> together, but it winds up correlating the curly brackets of functions in
> one version with the curly brackets of the next later function in the
> other version. This situation is *very ugly*, and can result in a totally
> unusable conflict file in the situation where you need such things to be
> presented coherently the most.

Comment: In my experience with XML for now, it gives exactly the same "bad" results as a normal diff.

Comment: I've had much better luck with patience diff with XML; certainly the diff I'm looking at currently has exactly the misalignment problem described with the regular diff algorithm, but looks absolutely grand with patience diff.

Comment: This blog has a great explaination, including an animated gif of the process: http://alfedenzo.livejournal.com/170301.html

Comment: I've found this blog very interesting and providing good explanation with further links to algorithms details: http://fabiensanglard.net/git_code_review/diff.php Hope it will be useful to someone

Comment: The frobnitz/fib/fact diff can be seen at https://gist.github.com/roryokane/6f9061d3a60c1ba41237

Answer (score 58):

You can also use it for merges (worked really well here for some XML conflicts):

```
git merge --strategy-option=patience ...
```

Comment: Or via `git config --global diff.algorithm patience`

Comment: Shorter would be `git merge -X patience`.

Comment: ... and short-form options ideally expect the "stuck" form (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcli)), so make it `git merge -Xpatience`

Answer (score 54):

The patience diff algorithm is a slower diff algorithm that shows better results in some cases.

Suppose you have the following file checked in to git:

```css
.foo1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.bar {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Now we reorder the sections and add a new line:

```css
.bar {
    margin: 0;
}

.foo1 {
    margin: 0;
    color: green;
}
```

The default diff algorithm claims that the section headings have changed:

```
$ git diff --diff-algorithm=myers   
diff --git a/example.css b/example.css
index 7f1bd1e..6a64c6f 100755
--- a/example.css
+++ b/example.css
@@ -1,7 +1,8 @@
-.foo1 {
+.bar {
     margin: 0;
 }

-.bar {
+.foo1 {
     margin: 0;
+    color: green;
 }
```

Whereas patience diff shows a result that is arguably more intuitive:

```
$ git diff --diff-algorithm=patience
diff --git a/example.css b/example.css
index 7f1bd1e..6a64c6f 100755
--- a/example.css
+++ b/example.css
@@ -1,7 +1,8 @@
-.foo1 {
-    margin: 0;
-}
-
 .bar {
     margin: 0;
 }
+
+.foo1 {
+    margin: 0;
+    color: green;
+}
```

There's [a good discussion of subjective diff quality here](http://fabiensanglard.net/git_code_review/diff.php), and [git 2.11 is exploring diff heuristics further](https://github.com/git/git/commit/433860f3d0beb0c6f205290bd16cda413148f098).

Note that the [patience diff algorithm still has some known pathological cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40159510/509706).