# difference between diff outputs using "git add --patch" and "filemerge"

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to use [`git add --patch`](http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git), and I noticed that it's diffs aren't the same as those generated using `opendiff`.

1. Is this common? Are there different diff algorithms? Am I just nuts?
2. Assuming the above is "yes", is there a way to force git to use the opendiff algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed different diff algorithms.  (And there are many possible diffs that will result in exactly the same change to a file - this is one of the reasons it's so sensible that git doesn't store changes, it only stores the state of the tree at each commit :))

Even within git, for some commands you can choose between two different diff algorithms - for example, try moving a function in some C code and compare the output of:

```
git diff
```

... and:

```
git diff --patience
```

The latter is usually more readable, albeit slower to calculate.

I'm not sure what algorithm opendiff uses, but perhaps it's similar to [patience diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4045017/223092)?

Unfortunately, I don't believe that it is currently possible in git to use a different diff algorithm in `git add -p`, although I would find that very useful too.  There is a [patch series here](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg752762.html) to add that feature, but it seems as if the author hasn't sent that upstream yet.