# In git, how do I increase the context for merges?

Tags: git, merge, diff, git-merge

When I merge large changes, git often gets hopelessly confused because it's not using enough context lines. It gets mixed up between the similar-looking endings of two different subroutines that both happen to end with:

```
.
return 1;
.
}
```

(dots used here to represent blank lines)

When I use 'git diff', I can say -U20 to see 20 lines of context. But can I tell git to use this flag when it merges, too?

Could the answer be related to merge strategies/options, such as:

```
git merge -s recursive -X patience [branch]
```

Comment: Related question about patience diff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045017/what-is-git-diff-patience-for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to increase the context lines during a merge. The *patience diff* algorithm is supposed to handle your use case better. The git-merge(1) man page describes it thus:

> With this option, merge-recursive spends a little extra time to
>   avoid mismerges that sometimes occur due to unimportant
>   matching lines (e.g., braces from distinct functions). Use this
>   when the branches to be merged have diverged wildly.

Since this looks exactly like the situation you're describing, patience seems custom-designed to help you out. You can try it out on a throw-away branch like so:

```
git checkout -b temp_merge_branch master
git merge --strategy-option=patience other_branch
```

If the merge works cleanly, you can fast-forward your master branch with the results. If not, you can just throw away the temporary branch, and look for other alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

Use these settings to get patience diffs with five lines of context everywhere:

```
git config --global diff.algorithm patience
git config --global diff.context 5
```

If you use `--color-words` often, this is useful as well:

```
git config --global diff.wordRegex '[A-z0-9_]+|[^[:space:]]'
```

The first setting requires [Git 1.8.2](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt).

Comment: For one timers you can use `git -c diff.context=5 merge -Xpatience <some-branch>`