# Use Git's patience diff algorithm for interactive add

Tags: git, git-diff, git-add, git-patch

I'd like to use Git's patience diff algorithm (the one you get if you invoke `git diff` with the `--patience` argument) with `git add -p`. How can I do this?

Background: I'm working with some XML files, and `git diff`'s normal algorithm [produces pretty poor diffs due to "misaligned" entry/exit tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045087/220155). If I run `git diff --patience`, I get much more useful diffs, but there's no obvious way to use these diffs in `git add -p`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that right now, but it sounds like a worthy suggestion to make to the `git` developers... In fact, there may be other `git diff` options that it would be useful to expose to `git add` and other places where an otherwise default-ish `git diff` is done...

Comment: see this line in the code : https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/add.c#L273

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`git add -p` currently rejects diff flags, but you can use the `diff.algorithm` config option:

```
git config --global diff.algorithm patience
```

New in [Git 1.8.2](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt).

Comment: Sweet! Now I just have to wait for Cygwin Git to catch up…

Comment: Should it also change algorithm for git commit?

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
git -c diff.algorithm=patience add -p [...]
```

I am running the latest git v2.1.0 in Cygwin.

Comment: Yes, as @Tobu already noted in the accepted answer, that config flag was added in Git v1.8.2. It turns out the way to get an up-to-date Git build on Cygwin is to take over the maintainership, which is exactly what I ended up doing :)

Comment: @me_and: then I have you to thank for finally getting updated versions of Cygwin git :) It's been inactive for quite some time.. As for my answer, I just wanted to show it's possible to change a config inline without modifying global configurations.

Comment: @me_and the interesting thing here is that this config option is only temporary and can be passed as cli-flag this way

Answer (score 5):

Hmmmm... One thing you could do is pipe the output of `git diff` to a temporary place, then read it back in with `git apply`:

```
git diff --patience <commitA> <commitB> > /tmp/patch.out
# checkout a new branch or otherwise do what you need to prep
git apply < /tmp/patch.out
```

That'll apply the output of the diff to the working directory, but it won't commit or stage the changes. You can then run `git add -p` as you normally would, and the `--patience` diff will be the changes you're interactively adding.

There's no reason you couldn't pipe `diff` to `apply` directly, if it better suits your workflow. It's something I do fairly regularly when rebuilding my own local branches for production integration.

Looks like you can also use it as a [merge strategy,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668051/877115) so it might be the case that instead of interactively adding the diffs, you could simply create a branch with what you want, then merge it in.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing; it lets me edit the patch, which is essentially what I'd like to do with `git add -p`. This just seems sadly more tedious than it ought to be.

Comment: @me_and Added some notes about using it as a merge strategy, too. Perhaps you could generate a trash merge branch with just the changes you wanted, then use the merge strategy to get a better result.