# how can I ignore comments in a 3-way merge?

Tags: git

So I've got the following repo: n1 -> n2 -> n3 -> master   and n2 -> n4

I want to merge n4 back into master using git, so AFIAK:

BASE = n2, LOCAL = n3, REMOTE = n4, and MERGED = master

I'm using p4merge to visualize the merge, but now the problem....

n2 and n4 have commented out sections of code that are slowly being uncommented in master... however the visual merge is totally screwed up... it seems that any commented line can match any other commented line... leading to all sorts of mismatches where commented functions are being matched to the middle of other code.  e.g.

LOCAL:

```
def foo
  impl foo
end

def bar
  impl bar
end
```

BASE/REMOTE:

```
# def foo
#   impl foo
# end 
#
# def bar
# end
```

MERGED:

```
def foo
  impl foo
  # def bar
  # end
end
```

Needless to say, I don't want the code merged like that.

I've read about custom merge drivers in git, but I'm not sure how to set them up... the idea is that I might get a better diff analysis if the diff tool could somehow ignore the comment character momentarily (while diffing) and then properly line things up.  I've tried to find a setting in p4merge to do that, but no luck.  There may be a way in kdiff3 as well, but I thought I'd try to figure out a way to do it with merge drivers first.

Any advice about setup or other ways to solve this problem would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should consider using another (better :X) diff/merge tool? Your case seems curious anyway, because a merge `n2 -> n4` into `n1 -> n2` results in a fast-forward, so there is no conflict possible.

Comment: I mean to say that at n2, I branched to n4 and then continued work in master and committed (edit: added n3 to desc above).  Now I'm trying to merge n4 back into master, so it's not a fast-forward in this case.  It's really a bear of a merge, I'm trying to port an app by commenting out the code in the old version and then selectively uncomment and test in the new version.  However, the old version has moved on, necessitating a comment of that old version, and then merging any changes into the new version.  I'm looking for answers.

Comment: I'll try kdiff3 tomorrow and see if it does a better job.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may help is the merge strategy option `patience`.  It does a better job at not jumbling up the code, and reports fewer and less severe merge conflicts.  It is used with a 'git merge --strategy-option=patience`.

A different question discussing the option in the `git diff` context is here, [What is 'git diff --patience' for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045017/what-is-git-diff-patience-for).

And of course, the option is described in the manual page for merge, [git merge manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).