# Git diff incorrectly interprets my changes

Tags: git, commit

The problem occurs when trying to diff blocks with same structure commonly appears in html/css for me.
Example:
[Initial commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxPiG.jpg)

Now lets add new param to "someblock" and new class "someotherblock".
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VFLL.jpg)

Expected result:

```
 1  1 .someblock
 2  2    height:100%;
    3+   width:100%;
 3  4 }
    5+.someotherblock{
    6+   height:100%;
    7+}
```

Is there any way to make git undestand "logic" of the changes?

Comment: Rather than looking at the actual diff, does Git get the merge done correctly?

Comment: Git's interpretation produces exactly the same result as yours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's important to realize that Git does not, and really *can* not, show you *exactly* what you did.  (Maybe you added the braces first, then added the contents, in that order, in which case to show you what you *did* it would have to say "first add both braces, then add the contents in between".)  Instead, Git simply produces a minimal<sup>1</sup> set of instructions that tell a *computer* how to change "what was there before" to "what should be there now".

The Git programmers try to make the "understandable to computer" instructions somewhat sensible to humans as well, but the answer to this:

> Is there any way to make git understand "logic" of the changes?

is "no".

The patience diff (see [Gira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950053/1256452)) can help for some cases, particularly those where Git synchronizes on lines consisting solely of open or close braces and the like.

Git 2.9 added a so-called "compaction heuristic" (described rather lightly [here](https://github.com/blog/2188-git-2-9-has-been-released)) but it requires a blank line above the changed region.  That phrase, "a blank line above", means *a blank line*, and *above*: the compaction heuristic doesn't believe the top of a file suffices (although in my opinion it *should* believe this).  The compaction heuristic makes a bigger difference, although for me, the idea of twisting the source just to make the VCS display better diffs is ... annoying, at least.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Minimal" in the sense of the fewest possible "delete X" and "add Y" instructions.  Git does not take into account the lengths of X and Y, which are typically lines, although Git does have word-oriented diff as well.  Ties—where Git could say "delete four lines here and add four there" and move the four around, up or down, get broken in favor of "furthest down" due to the algorithm used, which is why the compaction heuristic only tries to shift *up*.

Comment: Thats exaclty what i wanted to hear. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 5):

`git diff --histogram` is what you're looking for. It will display changes like this in a more human-readable way. It solves the problem of git diff showing brackets (curly braces) "wrong".

See [What's the difference between `git diff --patience` and `git diff --histogram`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365271/whats-the-difference-between-git-diff-patience-and-git-diff-histogram)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to call for a quick test:

```
git diff --patience
```

Or set the patience option globally for all diffs:

```
git config --global diff.algorithm patience
```

This will take more time to generate the diffs but should generate a nicer output.