# Where can i find the histogram diff algorithm on internet?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, string-comparison

Where can i find the histogram diff algorithm on internet. I want to compare two texts and find the differences, currently i am trying the patience diff algorithm,but that does not work that effective, i have heard like histogram diff algorithm is an improved version of patience diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git` software implements both patience and histogram diff algorithms. See also: [What's the difference between `git diff --patience` and `git diff --histogram`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365271/whats-the-difference-between-git-diff-patience-and-git-diff-histogram)

If you have git installed, the commands are:

```
git diff --histogram
git diff --patience
```

Your question has the `javascript` tag. I assume you are looking for a library, or a description of the algorithm so you can implement it yourself. The library used by `git` is **`libxdiff`**. Another diff library is `xdelta`.

Links:

- Libxdiff http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libxdiff
- XDelta http://xdelta.org/ https://github.com/jmacd/xdelta

Answer (score -1):

Even I have same requirement in my project I have used [this java-diff-utils](https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils) which implements

> 1. Meyer's diff
> 2. HistogramDiff algorithms