# What situations should the strategy-option flags be used in when doing a git merge? ( patience | minimal | histogram | myers )

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I want to get a high quality diff and I am not worried about how long it will take, e.g.

```
git merge --strategy-option=diff-algorithm=minimal develop
```

[From the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), Its not clear which one is best for which situations?

> - **default, myers** The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the
>     default.
> - **minimal** Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is
>     produced.
> - **patience** Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.
> - **histogram** This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support
>     low-occurrence common elements".

There is a [summary of the patience algorithm in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045087/296446).

- Is the histogram algorithm always be better than the patience algorithm since it extends it?
- Is the minimal algorithm better than the default since it 'spends extra time'?
- Are `--strategy-option=patience` and `--strategy-option=diff-algorithm=patience` equivalent?

Comment: Hmm - `git merge --strategy-option=minimal develop` dons't seem to work, minimal not recognised as a strategy.

Comment: I think you're confusing `git diff` strategies with `git merge` strategies and their associated options. These are not the same things...

Comment: @twalberg - I'm fairly sure that these options are also shared with the git merge command.  http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: You need to read the section of that manual page headed "MERGE STRATEGIES". If you want to specify a different `git diff` strategy option for the default recursive merge strategy, they syntax would be `git merge --strategy-option=diff-algorithm=minimal` for example, not `git merge --strategy-option=minimal` the way you have it stated... "patience" seems to be an exception, but the others are not valid as strategy options on their own... Not entirely sure if `git merge --strategy-option=patience` and `git merge --strategy-option=diff-algorithm=patience` are completely equivalent...

Comment: @twalberg - Cool thanks!  Ill adjust my question.

Answer (score 3):

You should always use histogram and not worry about it. The vast majority of the time all algorithms will give the exact same results, but once in a great while there will be an XML file or a heavily edited C file with lots of curly brackets where myers and minimal will merge up meaningless repeated sections of the file and have a completely broken and unusable output with unrelated sections of code on either side of conflict sections. Both patience and histogram will handle those cases fine, but histogram runs faster. Since histogram is both the best and fastest algorithm, there isn't much reason to use anything else.

Comment: Has there been some discussion of making it the default for git?  I'd be curious to see the arguments against.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the options available, histogram should provide the highest quality diff. It is also faster than patience, and the best for XML, HTML or other file formats that have multiple identical end tags or close parentheses / brackets / braces on a single line.